# C# How do i return iGrouping to a list using lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, dao

I am using entity framework to do this , i have this lambda expression :

```
public IList<Model.questionhint> GetRecordsPlease(int listTask, int listActivity)
{
   IList<Model.questionhint> lstRecords = context.questionhints.ToList();
   return lstRecords.GroupBy(x => new { 
                                      x.QuestionNo, 
                                      x.ActivityID, 
                                      x.TaskID })
                    .Where(a => a.Key.TaskID == listTask 
                             && a.Key.ActivityID == listActivity)
                    .ToList();         
}
```

but it says :

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<AnonymousType#1,iStellar.Model.questionhint>>`'
>   to '`System.Collections.Generic.IList<iStellar.Model.questionhint>`'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

This codes is in my CRUD class file named DAOQuestionHint .

How do i return this because i need to call it in my xaml.cs ( code behind ) like this :

> private DAO.DAOQuestionHint qh = new DAO.DAOQuestionHint();

```
IList<Model.questionhint> lstQuestionHints = qh.GetRecordsPlease(taskID, activityID);
```

This is how my database table looks like :

[image]

what i wanted is to group records of the same activityID , taskID and questionNo together in a line , now every record is seperated line by line like this :

[image]

i want it to be like

I [answer] to have a nap every afternoon

The sun [answer] not move round the earth.

So i tried to use alternative in code behind by using for loop but that doesn't work perfectly if there are 3 or more records of the same activityID , taskID and questionNo , so i tot i need to group them in the query first .

Comment: Well you've created a sequence of groups - how do you *want* to return* those as a single list. It's not clear what you expect the result to be. (I'd also suggest moving the `Where` call to *before* the `GroupBy` call - and as you'll only have one activity ID and one task ID, there's no point in grouping by those. You can just group by `QuestionNo`.)

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you don't need to group at all - you just need to filter. Unless you really have more than one hint per question (with the same task and activity), you just need:

```
public IList<Model.questionhint> GetRecordsPlease(int listTask, int listActivity)
{
    return context.questionhints
                  .Where(a => a.TaskID == listTask && a.ActivityID == listActivity)
                  .ToList();
}
```

Note that unlike your current code, this will perform the filtering in the database, rather than pulling the *whole* table to the client and then grouping/filtering. You need to be aware that any time you use `context.SomeTable.ToList()`, that will pull the entire contents of that table.

I'd also strongly suggest that you change your model to use type names which follow .NET naming conventions, so `QuestionHint` instead of `questionhint`.

(Finally, I'd remove the `Please` from the method name - computers don't need you to be polite in your naming like this.)

EDIT: If you really *do* want groups, you need to change the return value. For example, you could just return a sequence of groups:

```
public IList<IGrouping<int, Model.questionhint>>
     GetRecordsPlease(int listTask, int listActivity)
{
    return context.questionhints
                  .Where(a => a.TaskID == listTask && a.ActivityID == listActivity)
                  .ToList()
                  .GroupBy(a => a.QuestionNo)
                  .ToList();
}
```

I've deliberately called `ToList()` here before the grouping and then again afterwards so that the data is fetched once and you can iterate over those groups however you like without it going back to the database. (It's possible that just the final `ToList` would be enough, but I wouldn't like to say for sure.)

Comment: i did that before it works well but i need to group them because in the database , there are multiple records of the same QuestionNo .. some records have the same activity id and taskid but different questionNo , so i need to group them according .

Comment: @user2376998: But are there multiple records for the same question *and* the same task and activity? And if there are, how do you want them to be grouped in the result? Currently your method's return type is *just* a list of hints... it's not a list of groups of hints. You've got to decide what you actually want...

Comment: @user2376998: Well if you *do* want grouping, you'll need to change the return type, won't you? Again, I don't think you've really thought this through: you're saying you want a list of hints, but you also want them to be grouped. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: i need it to be grouped first and return that list of groups

Comment: @user2376998: Okay, I've edited my answer to show how that's easy to do. But you really need to think about what you want your method to return *first* in future - there's no point in starting off with the wrong return type and trying to shoehorn the data into it.

Comment: thanks for your time , actually i tried something similar as your code before after reading tuple in msdn , but the error still persists . Sorry please be patient with me , i am trying . I tried your above , error still persist.

Comment: @user2376998: "The error persists" doesn't really give me any more information, as you haven't said what the error is (with my code). Obviously you need to change your calling code to, in order to *expect* a list of groupings instead of a list of hints.